# Adding google scholar and Researchgate profile to the preamble in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, preamble, overleaf

I'm new to `Latex`. I am creating my resume using `moderncv` and I want to add my google scholar and researchgate profiles (icon and clickable link) to the preamble (below the website link in the image). Is there a simpler way to do that?
[image]

Here is my preamble:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
\usepackage{fontawesome}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

\usepackage{import}

% personal data

\vspace{-2.00cm}
\name {Md.Tahsin}{Mostafiz}
% \vspace{-.4cm}
% \title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\address{16/C Judges Complex, Kakrail, Dhaka}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\vspace{-.5cm}
\phone[mobile]{+88 01517262551}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{tahsinmostafiz314@gmail.com}                               %
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I got caught up on some other things and did not have the chance to edit my question or check the answers. However, your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you did not give us a complete MWE, I can only guess as to why you are using `\vspace{-2.00cm}` in your code/preamble. I suppose that it will not do what you want, but that is alas another question ;-)

A command exists for your problem: `\socials` in class `moderncv`:

```
\social[googlescholar]{john.doe} % <====================================
\social[researchgate]{john.doe} % <=====================================
```

`john.doe` stands for your account name in both cases.

To be able to use these commands you need to add the following code to your preamble:

```
% makes a https hyperlink
% usage: \httpslink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{% <=======================================
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}
    
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}~} % <===================
\newcommand*{\researchgatesocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-b}~} % <===================
\newcommand*{\testsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-c}~} % <===================

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    { 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{googlescholar}}{\collectionadd[googlescholar]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.googlescholar.com/profile/#3}}}{}% <================================================================
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{researchgate}}{\collectionadd[researchgate]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.researchgate.com/profile/#3}}}{}% <================================================================
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother
```

That allows you to use the given commands `\socials`.  Please note that you have to change the code `www.googlescholar.com/profile/` for

```
{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.googlescholar.com/profile/#3}}
```

to what you need. `#3` contains your displayed name, which is also the account name.

The second part you have to change is the following commands:

```
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}~}
```

Instead of `\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}` add the image you need, to display the logo of that page you did not tell us.

If the displayed name and the link differ in the last part (`john.doe` is not part of the link, but you want to display it, you can use the following command:

```
\social[test][www.test.com/profile/123456]{john.doe} % <=====================================
```

Then please change the second and third parameter to your needs. Instead of `test` use `googlescholar` and `researchgate` to name the new social commands.  BTW, if you only use the possibility of `test` you can use a shorter code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    { 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother
```

You need this code to get `https:` instead of `http:` in the links ...

With the following compilable code (MWE; please next time add one to your question!):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% makes a https hyperlink
% usage: \httpslink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{% <=======================================
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}
    
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}~} % <===================
\newcommand*{\researchgatesocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-b}~} % <===================
\newcommand*{\testsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-c}~} % <===================

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    { 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{googlescholar}}{\collectionadd[googlescholar]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.googlescholar.com/profile/#3}}}{}% <================================================================
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{researchgate}}{\collectionadd[researchgate]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.researchgate.com/profile/#3}}}{}% <================================================================
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother



% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[googlescholar]{john.doe} % <====================================
\social[researchgate]{john.doe} % <=====================================
\social[test][www.test.com/profile/john.doe]{john.doe} % <=====================================
\extrainfo{additional information}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt} 


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

you get:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Trying to load the logo can be problematic for some reason. Instead of file one can also use the fontawesome logos used for other socials logos. To do so add `\usepackage{fontawesome}` to the beginning of the preamble and change the relevant symbol line with: `\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}{{\small\faGraduationCap}~}`

Answer (score 1):

Sort of hacky method. Change the `\rule{1em}{1em}` to something that includes the logos you want.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
\usepackage{fontawesome}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

\usepackage{import}

% personal data

\vspace{-2.00cm}
\name{Md.\@ Tahsin}{Mostafiz}
% \vspace{-.4cm}
% \title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\address{16/C Judges Complex, Kakrail, Dhaka}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\vspace{-.5cm}
\phone[mobile]{+88 01517262551}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{tahsinmostafiz314@gmail.com}  

\homepage{google.com/scholar/something}
% change this to some \includegraphics with the logo you want
\renewcommand*\homepagesymbol{\rule{1em}{1em}}

\extrainfo{\rule{1em}{1em}\httplink{researchgate.com/users/someone}}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add a new class file name `moderncv.cls` and paste the code in the link
https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncv.cls

If you want to add icons then download the icon image from google search and upload on your project then find the line

```
\collectionnew{socials}
```

Then add the bellow code before it (as much copy as you needed)

```
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}~}
```

`example-image-a` is the corresponding image name.

Now use as follows -

```
\social[researchgate]{name}
\social[googlescholar]{id}
```