# How can I create a new line in \extrainfo of moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I am using the `casual` cv of the `moderncv` package.

Using the following:

```
\extrainfo{
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~JohnDoe]{www.xing.com/profile/john-doe/} 
\footsymbol \httplink[\faGithub~JohnDOe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~JohnDoe]{stackoverflow.com/users/john-doe}
}
```

It works fine, but the line is just too wide covering the page numbers.

I am not able to create a new line with `\newline` or `\\`.

Any suggestions?

---

Compilable Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}    
\address{Somewhere}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555} 
\email{my@email.com} 

\extrainfo{
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~JohnDoe]{www.xing.com/profile/john-doe/} 
\footsymbol \httplink[\faGithub~JohnDOe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~JohnDoe]{stackoverflow.com/users/john-doe}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a `\parbox` in `\extrainfo`, as in this example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}    
\address{Somewhere}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555} 
\email{my@email.com} 

\extrainfo{%
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
\centering
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~JohnDoe]{www.xing.com/profile/john-doe/}\\
\footsymbol \httplink[\faGithub~JohnDOe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~JohnDoe]{stackoverflow.com/users/john-doe}
}}

% without this you get a warning saying
% "Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (30.0pt):  Make it at least 58.40619pt."
% in your actual document the value might be different
\setlength\footskip{58.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are three issues in your code.

1. You did not define the length of `\footskip` you need to get a proper placed footer (the value may change depending on the personal informations you are using; check your log file for a warning `"Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (30.0pt):`. Use a value you need, in my case `\setlength{\footskip}{52pt}` ...
2. At last I guess you realy want to use command `\socials` instead your used `\extrainfo`. If you insist in using `\extrainfo` as a workaround simply change the `\footsymbol` to be a little bit shorter, then it does not write into the page number with your given personal informations:

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{{~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~}}
   ```

But the best solution for your issue is to use command `\social`. It is able to add your Xing, StackOverflow,Linkedin and Github informations to your personal datas in your footer in the simplest way (standard definitions):

```
\social[linkedin]{john-doe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
```

For Stackoverflow and Xing we have to do a little bit more:

```
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}{\faXing~}
\social[xing][xing.com/JohnDoe]{JohnDoe}
\newcommand*{\SOfsocialsymbol}{\faStackOverflow~}
\social[SOf][www.StackOverflow.com/profile/john.doe]{john.doe}
```

Change `www.StackOverflow.com/profile/john.doe` to your real datas, for example `tex.stackexchange.com/users/179843`.

3. Having a closer look to the used links in your cv, you will see that in the standard definition only `http://` is used instead to today used `https://`. To solve this issue please have a look to my answer for question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464850/16550.

With the following MWE I show you the solutions for issue 1 and two together (see markings in code `<========`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setlength{\footskip}{52pt}% <==========================================
\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{{~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~}} % <===========

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}    
\address{Somewhere}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555} 
\email{my@email.com} 

\social[linkedin]{john-doe} % <=========================================
\social[github]{jdoe}
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}{\faXing~}
\social[xing][xing.com/JohnDoe]{JohnDoe}
\newcommand*{\SOfsocialsymbol}{\faStackOverflow~}
\social[SOf][www.StackOverflow.com/profile/john.doe]{john.doe}
\social[github]{jdoe} % <===============================================

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
test
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf page:

[image]

In your comment you asked "Is there a way to start with the first social on a new line?".  Well, you can add the command `\flushfoot\\` in the definition of command `\makecvfoot` where you need it:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{0.9\textwidth}}% <=============================
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
\flushfoot\\% <===================================
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother
```

With the new complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setlength{\footskip}{52pt}% <==========================================
%\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{{~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~}} % <===========

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}    
\address{Somewhere}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555} 
\email{my@email.com} 

\social[linkedin]{john-doe} % <=========================================
\social[github]{jdoe}
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}{\faXing~}
\social[xing][xing.com/JohnDoe]{JohnDoe}
\newcommand*{\SOfsocialsymbol}{\faStackOverflow~}
\social[SOf][www.StackOverflow.com/profile/john.doe]{john.doe}
\social[github]{jdoe} % <===============================================

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
\flushfoot\\% <===================================
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
test
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting footer:

[image]

To remove the bullet in front of the linkedin logo you have to add `\@firstfootelementtrue` after `\flushfoot`.

With the new MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setlength{\footskip}{52pt}% 
%\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{{~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~}} % 

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}    
\address{Somewhere}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555} 
\email{my@email.com} 

\social[linkedin]{john-doe} % 
\social[github]{jdoe}
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}{\faXing~}
\social[xing][xing.com/JohnDoe]{JohnDoe}
\newcommand*{\SOfsocialsymbol}{\faStackOverflow~}
\social[SOf][www.StackOverflow.com/profile/john.doe]{john.doe}
\social[github]{jdoe} % 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
\flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\% <===================================
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
test
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Comment: that solution is much better, one more thing though, is there any way to remove the bullet in front of the linkedin logo?