# IFACconf - How to include ORCID in LaTeX

Tags: document-classes

I'm trying to include OCRID-iDs (unique identifier for authors) to the LaTeX-template of the IFAC conferences (IFAC is the larges community for automation and control). However, in spite of the large community, I couldn't find a way to do so.

The [guidelines](https://orcid.org/content/journal-article-display-guidelines) of ORCID state:

> **1. Display in author list**: The iD, hyperlinked to the author’s ORCID iD URI, immediately follows the author’s name on the first page of the article. Where the iD icon is displayed, a buffer of 50% of the iD width should be used.
>
> **Article title**
>
> [image: ORCIDID Author list]

I found this [nice post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445563/ieeetran-how-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf-with-pdflatex) here but none of the solutions worked (`\includegraphics` of the .png, or defining a custom command to display the .svg file directly + hyperlinks):

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
    orcidlogo/.pic={
        \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
        \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
        svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
        svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
    }
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel*{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,transform shape]
                \pic{orcidlogo};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }{|}}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Title goes here}
    \author{John Doe \orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
    \maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

[Other posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501686/add-orcid-logo-to-moderncv-using-classic-style) suggest that the ORCID-logo is included in the `academicons` package, but this neither worked

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{academicons}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Title goes here}
    \author{John Doe \aiOrcid}
    \maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

The IFAC template can be downloaded [here](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/resolveuid/b0e4734736878819db179d76290a8f78) (coming from this site https://www.ifac-control.org/events/authors-guide) -- which includes the *ifacconf.cls*.

I'm stunned that I'm the only one encountering this problem as both communities are large and usually work with LaTeX. Does anyone has an idea or a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`academicons` package**

Your second approach needs `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile. If this is an option, here's a MWE. (I had to load the `natbib` package to avoid compiling errors.)

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\definecolor{idcolor}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\color{idcolor}\aiOrcid}}

\begin{document}

    \title{Title goes here}
    \author{John Doe \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

**Include SVG ORCID logo**

You can include the `ORCIDiD_iconvector.svg` logo from the [ORCID website](https://figshare.com/articles/ORCID_iD_icon_graphics/5008697) using the `svg` package. This method requires `inkscape` in your `PATH` and the `--shell-escape` option when compiling with `pdflatex` (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package)).

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includesvg[height = 2ex]{ORCIDiD_iconvector}}}

\begin{document}
    \title{Title goes here}
    \author{John Doe \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, I'll check if `xelatex` or `lulatex` are OK (never new the difference though). However, the examples are compiled with `latex`

Comment: You're welcome. I added another solution for `pdflatex` which requires Inkscape.

Comment: thx for the help =)