# Icons in ModernCV

Tags: git, icon, google-scholar

I would like to update my CV and add also icons for linking, google schola, email, git and website.

I would like to be in the top right place, something like that

```
Name                IconWebsite IconEmail IconLinkedn IconGit etc
```

The CV that I have already is in the following format

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} \setul{1ex}{0.8ex} \definecolor{orange}{rgb}{73,,0}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setulcolor{orange}

%% connect text with internet 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

%% Personal data
\firstname{XXXXX}

%\mobile{XXXX}
\email{XXXXX}
\homepage{XXXXXX}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\vspace*{-10mm}

\section{Personal statement}

\small XXXXXXX 

\section{Education} 
\cvitem{XX -- XX}{\textbf{XXX}\newline
XXXX:
\begin{itemize}
\item XXXX
\item XXXX
\end{itemize} 
}

\end{document}
```

I have already checked this post [Adding google scholar and Researchgate profile to the preamble in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464832/adding-google-scholar-and-researchgate-profile-to-the-preamble-in-moderncv), but the code is not working for google scholar

Comment: What distribution in what version are you using. I tried to compile your MWE with Texlive 2022 up to date but first I need to have both `\firstname{}` and `\lastname{}` otherwise I'm having "Undefined control sequence. <argurment> \@firstname {}~ \@lastname {}" error :s Second, I had "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref." error because it's already loaded by `moderncv` and when I comment it `\hypersetup{` became an "Undefined control sequence" until moved from preamble to document body (or let it in preamble but load package with option `unicode`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working into my code:

```
\usepackage{academicons}

\extrainfo{
        \faEnvelope\href{mailto:xxx}{ Email} \quad
        \aiGoogleScholarSquare\href{xxx}{ GoogleScholar} \quad
        \faLinkedin\href{xxx}{ Linkedin}  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some icons (with text) are provided with dedicated commands: `\email{}`, `\fax{}` or `\phone[fax]{}`, `\mobile{}` or `\phone[mobile]{}`, `\phone[fixed]{}` or just `\phone{}`, `\homepage{}`. For other icons, there's now the `\social[type]{account}` (with option type like `linkedin`/`stackoverflow`/`github`/etc.)

Not all social type are available. To add some others, here's how I did:

1. First load `fontawesome` or, better, [`fontawesome5`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) package before all
2. Choose a key, for example GS for Google Scholar,
3. Associate that key with a symbol (hence the Font Awesome package), here [`mendeley`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/541#issuecomment-446348271) or `graduationCap`
4. Now use the variant `\social[key][link]{display}` (link is without `https://` prefix)

Let's put all that together with the code

```latex
\documentclass{moderncv}
%…
\usepackage{fontawesome5} %1. to use the faIconName
%…
\newcommand*\GSsocialsymbol{\faMendeley~} %3. Association key-symbol
\social[GS][www.googlescholar.com/profile/myself]{myself} %4. 
%…
\begin{document}
%…
\end{document}
```

The link you pointed use image instead of FA icons. The previous list becomes

1. Grab the the associated image, and load `graphicx` package
2. Still choose a key
3. Associate that key with that image
4. Use the variant `\social[key][link]{display}`

I didn't test but I'm quite confident. Maybe you'll need to load `graphicx` too (but I think it's already done for commands like `photo[][]{}`)

```latex
\documentclass{moderncv}
%…
\usepackage{graphicx} %1. to use \includegraphics
%…
\newcommand*\GSsocialsymbol{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{path-to-image}~} %3. 
\social[GS][www.googlescholar.com/profile/myself]{myself} %4. 
%…
\begin{document}
%…
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce. Strange I didn't notice that (maybe because I redefined label items?) Switching to `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` solve it.